# How to listen to azure storage queue with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

Azure storage queue is not listening to the message automatically when we push to the queue, we have to write a custom lister in-order to fetch the message from the queue.

```
import {
  QueueServiceClient,
} from "@azure/storage-queue";

// Create a QueueServiceClient object
const queueServiceClient = QueueServiceClient.fromConnectionString("AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;");

// // Create a new queue
const queueName = "test-local-queue";
const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(queueName);
queueClient.create().then(() => {
  console.log(`Queue "${queueName}" was created successfully`);
});

// Add a message to the queue
const message = "Hello, world!";
queueClient.sendMessage(message).then(() => {
  console.log(`Message "${message}" was added to the queue`);
});

// Set the number of messages to retrieve (up to 32)
const maxMessages = 10;

// Set the visibility timeout (in seconds) for the messages
const visibilityTimeout = 60;

// Receive messages from the queue
queueClient
  .receiveMessages({ maxMessages, visibilityTimeout })
  .then(response => {
    const messages = response.receivedMessageItems;
    console.log(`Received ${messages.length} messages from the queue`);

    // Process the messages
    messages.forEach(message => {
      console.log(message);
      // Do something with the message...
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(`Failed to receive messages from the queue: ${error}`);
  });
```

Does Azure service bus solves the above stated problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Well instead of `recievemessage` function try `peekmessage` .
- In this function by default it will peek at a single message but you can configure it the way you want. Here I have configured it to peek 3 messages.

```
const  peekedMessages = await  queueClient.peekMessages({ numberOfMessages:  3 });
```

Now the `peekMessages` const contains an array called `peekedMessageItems` which will contain the peeked messages

- here I have just iterated in that array and read the messages using `messageText` property

Complete Code:

```
const { QueueClient, QueueServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-queue");

  

const  queueServiceClient = QueueServiceClient.fromConnectionString(conn);

const  queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient(qname);

const  peekedMessages = await  queueClient.peekMessages({ numberOfMessages:  3 });

for (i = 0; i < peekedMessages.peekedMessageItems.length; i++) {

    // Display the peeked message

    console.log("Peeked message: ", peekedMessages.peekedMessageItems[i].messageText);

}
```

[image]

- Also as the name suggest this will peek message not dequeue them.

Comment: I think still we have to call the peekMessages function for fetching new msgs when it been pushed to the queue.

  setInterval(() => await fetchNewMessageFromQueue, 5000);